# How to access and change properties of all the objects of a class at once?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, class

I want to update the properties of all objects of a particular class with time. Is there a short way to access all the objects of a class and update them?

```
class Ships {
constructor(width, height) {
  this.width = width * scaleFactor; // scaleFactor will change on rotation or resize of the window
  this.height = height * scaleFactor;
}
}
var ship1 = new Ships(100,180);
var ship2 = new Ships(50,100); //there will be multiple ships, so I can't push them in an **array**
```

I want to update the width and height of all ships when the window resizes or rotates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getters` for that:

```
class Ships {
constructor(width, height) {
this._width = width;
this._height = height;
}
  get width() {
return this._width * scaleFactor;
} 
  get height() {
return this._height * scaleFactor;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let arr = [
  ... // the array with various types of objects
];

for (let item of arr) {
   if (item instanceof Ship) {
     // we sure here that item is an instance of Ship class
     updateShip(item)
   }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way without using arrays... like: `Ships.width = Ships.width` _just for updating the value_ . I want to update the values of the created objects of this class. I guess there should be a way for changing the values of all objects by changing the value in the class. For example: if there are 10 objects created in class Ships, then we should be able to change the widths and heights of all objects by editing in the *class Ships* :/